# fetch array from url via GET request

Tags: php, arrays

Am trying to fetch an array from url via get request but am unable to do that

This is my URL with values encoded

```
    http://example.com/q.php?sub[]=xyz&sub[]=wsq
```

this is how am trying to store the values in another array

```
    $sub= array();
    $sub[]= $_GET['sub[]'];
```

Am not getting any result but if I run my page by manually initializing the array am getting the desired result without any issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, just access it as `$_GET['sub'];` in turn, it'll return an array of values.

Then you could just iterate it just like any array:

```
foreach($_GET['sub'] as $sub) {
    echo $sub;
}
```

What it should [look](http://codepad.viper-7.com/3Er1uC?sub[]=xyz&sub[]=wsq) like.

Comment: But it doesn't behave as an array . means if i use foreach loop then it gives a blank result

Comment: sorry sorry my mistake. i got the desired result. thanks a lot

Comment: @user3225075 yes it will behave like an array if you put them in a grouping name key parameter, check out what i mean http://codepad.viper-7.com/8PgIcw?sub[]=xyz&sub[]=wsq